# hook postNotificaiton using Frida

Tags: nsnotifications, frida

I am trying to hook postNotificationName Function with Frida. I call two functions:

- postNotificationName:(NSNotificationName)object:(id)userInfo:(NSDictionary)
- postNotification:(NSNotification)object

sO, When I trace the functions using frida-trace, I see that in the later case there is calls to postNotificationName. I want to know if postNotification calls postNotification and why is that?

Also,

```
var newObject = ObjC.classes.NSNotification;
var myObj = newObject.alloc().initWithName_object_userInfo_('notificationName','nil','userInfo');
var hook = ObjC.classes.NSNotificationCenter["- postNotification:"];
Interceptor.attach(hook.implementation, {
    onEnter: function(args) {
        console.log("\n[*] Detected call to: " + NsNotificationCenter + " -> " + postNotification);
        console.log("\t[-] Argument Value: " + args[2]);
        args[2] = ptr(myObj)
        console.log("\t[-] New Argument Value: " + args[2])
    }
```

works when is injected using Frida to hook the postNotification function.
However,

```
var nsName = ObjC.classes.NSString;
var notificationName= nsName.stringWithString_("Blah"); 
var hook = ObjC.classes.NSNotificationCenter["- postNotificationName:"];
Interceptor.attach(hook.implementation, {
    onEnter: function(args) {
        console.log("\n[*] Detected call to: " + NSNotificationCenter + " -> " + postNotificationName);
        console.log("\t[-] Argument Value: " + args[2]);
        args[2] = ptr(notifname)
        console.log("\t[-] New Argument Value for postNotificaitonName: " + args[2])
    }
});
```

is not working for the postNotificationName:Object:userInfo. I guess the issue is in the line "var hook = ObjC.classes.NSNotificationCenter["- postNotificationName:"];".
Does anyone know what is wrong with it and how to make it work please?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotificationcenter) the class `NSNotificationCenter` has no selector `"- postNotificationName:"`.

There are two selectors with that name but they have additional parameters:

- `"- postNotificationName:object:userInfo:"`
- `"- postNotificationName:object:"`

If you want to hook any of these selectors you have to use the full selector string as stated above for hooking:

```
var hook = ObjC.classes.NSNotificationCenter["- postNotificationName:object:userInfo:"];
```

or

```
var hook = ObjC.classes.NSNotificationCenter["- postNotificationName:object:"];
```